# Cordova: Execute script to open link in External browser

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser, javascript-injection

I am creating  app in Cordova,I have used In appBrowser in it. I have set

```
<external-url>
<url>www.google.com</url>
</external-url>

  function loadWebApplication(startUrl) {
    //* trust Unsecure Cert for UAT
    cordova.plugins.certificates.trustUnsecureCerts(true)

    if (getInternetConnectionStatus()) {
        _startUrl = startUrl + "?appUUID=" + getAppUuid(win);

        //* call in app browser to open startUrl
        if (win.device.platform == 'iOS') {
            //* different in app browser option for ios
            _inAppBrowserHandler = window.open(_startUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
        } else if (win.device.platform == 'Android') {
            //* different in app browser option for Android         
            _inAppBrowserHandler = window.open(_startUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes');
        }


        _inAppBrowserHandler.addEventListener('loadstart', onInAppBrowserStart);
        _inAppBrowserHandler.addEventListener('loadstop', onInAppBrowserStop);
        _inAppBrowserHandler.addEventListener('loaderror', onInAppBrowserLoadError);
        _inAppBrowserHandler.addEventListener('exit', onInAppBrowserExit);
    } else {
        doc.location.href = "error.html";
    }

}
```

The above code is to load the starting URL. Now What I want here is in           `_inAppBrowserHandler.addEventListener('loadstop', onInAppBrowserStop);`

this method fetch all the  and in execute script check for the links which matches the External url link. If it matches I want to open it in external browser otherwise it will open it in an internal browser.

Now I know that I need to write code in execute script but I am completely new Cordova /javascript  so I have no idea what needs to be written in execute script.

```
_inAppBrowserHandler.executeScript({
            code: " "
        }, function () {
            alert("Code added");
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried using [loadstart](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#inappbrowseraddeventlistener) event?

Comment: yes, I am using loadstart

Comment: Could you extend the question with what you have tried (some code snippets)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294882/open-link-in-external-browser-from-android-with-cordova?rq=1 see if this helps (`window.onclick`)